# Rails 4: will_paginate error when trying to Sort a Resource Based on a Calculated Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I use Rails 4.1.0 I want to sort profiles based on completeness so for this i have this code in my profile model

```
def completeness
    percent = 10

    percent += 15 if self.useravatar.present?
    percent += 5 if self.summary.present?
    percent += 5 if self.profile_languages.present?
    percent += 10 if self.educations.present?
    return percent
end

def self.sorted_by_completeness
  Profile.all.sort_by(&:completeness).reverse
end
```

and this is my profiles index controller

```
  def index
    @profiles = Profile.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).sorted_by_completeness
  end
```

But when I'm trying to access profile index page I'm getting this error `undefined method`total_pages' for #` can someone tell me why i'm getting this error

Answer (score 2):

`sort_by` will return `Array` collection

to test open rails console and type

```
Profile.all.sort_by(&:completeness).reverse.class
```

for will_paginate to work with Array you need to  `require 'will_paginate/array'` 
so just change your profile_controller as

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @profiles = Profile.sorted_by_completeness.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with your approach:

1. In your view, you're probably using `will_paginate(@projects)` which fails because that method isn't for arrays.
2. You're sorting the rows **after** they've been paginated. This means that however you sort them, the sorting will be applied to only one page at a time. Thus whatever solution you choose, you need to specify the order before you paginate the data.

A solution would be to obviously use pagination on your array. Something like:

```
require 'will_paginate/array' # to enable pagination on an array
@projects = Project.sorting_method.paginate(arguments)
```

However for a large number of projects, that will soon become impractical.

The best way IMO, to enable pagination, is to have a `completeness` field in your `projects` table that gets updated anytime it should. Then, you could very easily do the following:

```
@projects = Project.order("completeness DESC").paginate(arguments)
```

Another solution would be to use sub-queries in a SQL select statement to calculate each project's completeness. Something like:

```
lcq = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM profile_languages WHERE
  (profile_languages.project_id = projects.id)"
ecq = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM educations WHERE
  (educations.project_id = projects.id)"

@projects = \
  Project.select(
    "#{project.column_names.join(',')},
    SELECT(
      (CASE useravatar WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 15 END) +
      (CASE summary WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 5 END) +
      (CASE (#{lcq}) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 5 END) +
      (CASE (#{ecq}) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 10 END)
    ) AS completeness").
  order("completeness DESC").
  paginate(arguments)
```

With some debugging, that should work. I don't like it though. A bunch of code that is hard to read and sub-queries that might slow things down a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def index
  @profiles = Profile.sorted_by_completeness(params[:page])
 end
```

**In your model file:**

```
def self.sorted_by_completeness(current_page)
    Profile.all.sort_by(&:completeness).reverse.paginate(page: current_page)
end
```

**TO define your per_page limit use below code:**

```
 #app/config/initializers/will_paginate.rb 
  WillPaginate.per_page = 10
```

**Else if you want to define it in model level:**

```
  #profile.rb
   class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
      self.per_page = 10
    #your other model level logic goes here.
    end
```